# How to fix the exception when install the module?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have the exception when install new instances (56%) as below

> An error occured during installation...
>
> You can use the links on the left column to go back to the previous
>   steps, or restart the installation process by clicking here.

[image]

How I can fix this ?

**Info:**

- Ver:  prestashop_1.5.6.3
- Host: azure
- Web server
- Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.46
- PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
- PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

Answer (score 0):

After Googling for the issue, one of the user gave the below solution for a similar issue.

```
Checked permissions on the .htaccess (which is at the root), 
and see to it that it is at 644.
```

Comment: Ver 1.5.6.3 it haven't .htaccess file in root folder, could you please provide more details for me? thanks !

Comment: Check in the prestashop's installed directory folder